# Prevent mouse events to go through child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, dom-events

In the example below, mouse events are going through the child (list items) when the mouse is between the item label and the horizontal colored bar.

This results in the item de-emphasizing although the mouse in still in its bounds. This is because of the margin I think... how could I prevent this?

```js
const parent = document.querySelectorAll(".parent")[0];
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".parent li");

items.forEach((item) =>
    item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => setHint(item))
);

parent.addEventListener("mouseout", () => setHint(false));

function setHint(item) {
    if (item) {
        items.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add(i === item ? "hovered" : "not-hovered");
        });
    } else {
        items.forEach((i) => {
            i.className = "";
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
}

.parent li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent li.hovered {
  opacity: 1;
}

.parent li.not-hovered {
  opacity: 0.1 !important;
}

.parent li > span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child-label {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.child-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: rgb(186, 186, 186);
}

.child-bar-fill {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
  background: #fe512c;
}
```

```html
<ul class='parent'>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Lorem ipsum</b>
            <span>8 045</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 36.6749%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Dolor sit amet</b>
            <span>8 701</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 39.6654%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Consectetur adipiscing</b>
            <span>144</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.656455%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Sed do eiusmod</b>
            <span>806</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 3.67433%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Incididunt ut labore</b>
            <span>149</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.679249%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Dolore magna aliqua</b>
            <span>470</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 2.1426%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Enim ad minim veniam</b>
            <span>73</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.332786%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Cupidatat non proident</b>
            <span>87</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.396608%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Reprehenderit in voluptate</b>
            <span>3 461</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 15.7777%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In `.parent li` change `margin-bottom` to `padding-bottom`.

Comment: @ciekals11 it's not the space between items which is bothering me but the space between each item's label and bar. I tried to replace margin by padding in `.child-label` but it's the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your current setup and JS all you need is [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) adding to your label and bars.

Because you are essentially targeting `mouseover` (via `mouseenter` and `mouseout`) for the `<li>`, when your mouse is over the label or bar it is no longer the item that is receiving `mouseover` and so triggers `mouseout`.

By adding `pointer-events:none` we are telling the browser to ignore all events on this item and let them pass through to the item below.

```js
const parent = document.querySelectorAll(".parent")[0];
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".parent li");

items.forEach((item) =>
    item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => setHint(item))
);

parent.addEventListener("mouseout", () => setHint(false));

function setHint(item) {
    if (item) {
        items.forEach((i) => {
            i.classList.add(i === item ? "hovered" : "not-hovered");
        });
    } else {
        items.forEach((i) => {
            i.className = "";
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
}

.parent li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.parent li.hovered {
  opacity: 1;
}

.parent li.not-hovered {
  opacity: 0.1 !important;
}

.parent li > span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child-label {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.child-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: rgb(186, 186, 186);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.child-bar-fill {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
  background: #fe512c;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class='parent'>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Lorem ipsum</b>
            <span>8 045</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 36.6749%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Dolor sit amet</b>
            <span>8 701</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 39.6654%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Consectetur adipiscing</b>
            <span>144</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.656455%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Sed do eiusmod</b>
            <span>806</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 3.67433%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Incididunt ut labore</b>
            <span>149</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.679249%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Dolore magna aliqua</b>
            <span>470</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 2.1426%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Enim ad minim veniam</b>
            <span>73</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.332786%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Cupidatat non proident</b>
            <span>87</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.396608%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Reprehenderit in voluptate</b>
            <span>3 461</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 15.7777%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was exactly what I was looking for. I stumbled accross `pointer-events` but I wouldn't have thought it was actually the problem here. Thanks!

Comment: I see you added a `display: block;` in `.parent li`. Was that necesary?

Comment: You are more than welcome, as for the `display: block`...no that was a mistake to leave that in , I was just fiddling about as I thought it was a layout issue then spotted the problem, you can ignore that!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can solve your problem with a CSS only approach like the one below, combining `parent:hover` and `parent li:hover`.

```css
.parent {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
}

.parent li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

.parent:hover li {
    opacity: 0.1;
}

.parent:hover li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.parent li > span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child-label {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.child-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: rgb(186, 186, 186);
}

.child-bar-fill {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
  background: #fe512c;
}
```

```html
<ul class='parent'>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Lorem ipsum</b>
            <span>8 045</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 36.6749%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Dolor sit amet</b>
            <span>8 701</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 39.6654%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Consectetur adipiscing</b>
            <span>144</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.656455%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Sed do eiusmod</b>
            <span>806</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 3.67433%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Incididunt ut labore</b>
            <span>149</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.679249%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Dolore magna aliqua</b>
            <span>470</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 2.1426%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Enim ad minim veniam</b>
            <span>73</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.332786%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Cupidatat non proident</b>
            <span>87</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 0.396608%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='child-label'>
            <b>Reprehenderit in voluptate</b>
            <span>3 461</span>
        </span>
        <span class='child-bar'>
            <span class='child-bar-fill' style='width: 15.7777%;'></span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gets my vote, was just about to add that to my answer but no point now!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But actually I prefer to keep my current setup 

Comment: BTW, there's a margin between the <li> items. Using padding instead of a margin you can avoid no items being selected while hovering between items.

Comment: @Drarig29 I'm curious, why would you keep the JS if it works without?

Comment: @sigmus that's because I'm actually using React and the approach is much simpler than this JS snippet. This snippet was only for the reproducible example. All my components are written like this. But you're right, I'll try the CSS-only approach

Comment: Sorry I won't mark your answer accepted because this is a (very good) workaround but not the solution to the initial problem... hope you understand :)

Comment: @Drarig29 Not here chasing points, I actually learned something :-)